# display parsed date from AFNetworking3 to display only passed hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios10

I am trying to display parsed date from AFNetworking3 to display only passed hours, not full date, like 1 hour ago..etc.
I used this to get the full date

```
    allData = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSDictionary *data = [allData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.created_at.text = [data objectForKey:@"created_at"];
```

This is the link of json data:
http://mkssab.com/api/index

Comment: You need to first transform the NSString (which represent a date) into a NSDate object using a NSDateFormatter. Then you can look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487465/how-to-convert-nsdate-in-to-relative-format-as-today-yesterday-a-week-ago

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for converting string into NSDate and calculating the difference b/w current date and date.

```
//This piece of code get the date from created date
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* createdOn = [formatter dateFromString:[data objectForKey:@"created_at"]];

//This piece of code calculates the difference b/w created date and current date.
NSTimeInterval interval = [createdOn timeIntervalSinceDate:NSDate.date];
NSInteger hours = interval/3600;
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate?language=objc

Comment: That shouldn't work or maybe gives wrong dates: "yyyy" and "HH" should be used instead of "YYYY" and "hh".